# Convert two forEach into map

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

How to convert this two loops forEach into map function?

```
var storedNames = [1,2,3];
var mod = {id: 3, blocList: [{id:11}, {id:12}]};

storedNames.forEach((item: number) => {
  if (item === mod.id) {
    mod.blocList.forEach((bloc: Bloc) => {
      storedNames.push(bloc.id);
    });
  }
});
```

The result will be: `storedNames = [1, 2, 3, 11, 12]`

Comment: Can `storedNames` have duplicates? What should happen if it has the value 3 twice? Are you sure it should then add 11 and 12 twice also?

Comment: I use a Set on my array to remove duplications 
storedNames = Array.from(new Set(storedNames))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but it is not a perfect use of `Array.map()`. Ideally, you'd use map if you want to keep the storedNames intact and create a copy of it with the changes that loop makes. Such as:

```
modifiedStoredNames = storedNames.map(//do stuff);
```

To my understanding, map is a way of making a copy of an array with the modifications applied for each elements using the function passed as parameter. In this case, we're just using `map()` to loop (two loops to be precise) and updating the array `storedNames` based on a condition within that loop. **And ignoring what map really returns.**

```
storedNames.map((item: number) => {
  if (item === mod.id) {
    mod.blocList.map((bloc: any) => {
      storedNames.push(bloc.id);
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#map` and `array#concat` to generate the desired array.

```js
var storedNames = [1,2,3],
    mod = {id: 3, blocList: [{id:11}, {id:12}]},
    result = [...storedNames].concat(mod.blocList.map(({id}) => id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` in combination with spread syntax, like this:

```js
var storedNames = [1,2,3];
var mod = {id: 3, blocList: [{id:11}, {id:12}]};

if (storedNames.some(item => item == mod.id)) {
    storedNames.push(...mod.blocList.map(bloc => bloc.id));
}

console.log(storedNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below code. Here I have just tried to obtain the output that you want.

If you have more data with different forms then in that case you will need to modify the code based on your target result.

> **Note:** Here you are using Typescript and my answer is in pure JavaScript (Node.js), so please do not forget to specify the type of variables in **parameter-list** or in **initialization** statements like `function(item){...}` to `function(item: number){...}` etc.

```
var storedNames = [1,2,3];
var mod = {id: 3, blocList: [{id:11}, {id:12}]};

var storedNames = storedNames.map(function(item) {
    if(item === mod.id) {
        var bArr = [item]; // [3]
        var cArr = mod.blocList.map((bloc) => {
            return(bloc.id); // Returning 11 and 12 one after one
        });

        bArr = bArr.concat(cArr);
        // console.log(cArr); /* [ 11, 12 ] */
        // console.log(bArr); /* [ 3, 11, 12 ] */
        return bArr;
    }
    return item; // Returning 1 and 2 one after one
}) 

console.log(storedNames);  // [ 1, 2, [ 3, 11, 12 ] ]

//Finally
storedNames = storedNames.concat(storedNames.splice(storedNames.length - 1, 1)[0]); 

console.log(storedNames); // [ 1, 2, 3, 11, 12 ]
```